# spark : use the global config variables in executors

Tags: apache-spark

I have a global config Object in my spark app.

```
Object Config {
 var lambda = 0.01
}
```

and I will set the value of lambda according to user's input.

```
Object MyApp {
   def main(args: String[]) {
     Config.lambda = args(0).toDouble
     ...
     rdd.map(_ * Config.lambda)
   }
}
```

and I found that the modification does not take effect in executors. The value of lambda is always 0.01. I guess the modification in driver's jvm will not effect the executor's.

Do you have other solution ?

I found a similar question in stackoverflow :

[how to set and get static variables from spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685330/how-to-set-and-get-static-variables-from-spark)

in @DanielL.  's answer, he gives three solutions:

1. Put the value inside a closure to be serialized to the executors to perform a task.

**But I wonder how to write the closure and how to serialized it to the executors, could any one give me some code example?**

2.If the values are fixed or the configuration is available on the executor nodes (lives inside the jar, etc), then you can have a lazy val, guaranteeing initialization only once.

what if I declare the lambda as a lazy val variable? the modification in the driver will take effects in the executors? could you give me some code example?

3.Create a broadcast variable with the data. I know this way, but it also need a local Broadcast[] variable which wraps the Config Object right? for example:

```
val config = sc.broadcast(Config)
```

and use `config.value.lambda` in executors , right ?

Answer (score 4):

1. Put the value inside a closure

```scala
object Config {var lambda = 0.01}
object SOTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("StaticVar"))
    val r = sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 3)
    Config.lambda = 0.02
    mul(r).collect.foreach(println)
    sc.stop()
  }
  def mul(rdd: RDD[Int]) = {
    val l = Config.lambda
    rdd.map(_ * l)
  }
}
```

2. lazy val for only once initialisation

```scala
object SOTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    lazy val lambda = args(0).toDouble
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("StaticVar"))
    val r = sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 3)
    r.map(_ * lambda).collect.foreach(println)
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

3. Create a broadcast variable with the data

```scala
object Config {var lambda = 0.01}
object SOTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("StaticVar"))
    val r = sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 3)

    Config.lambda = 0.04
    val bc = sc.broadcast(Config.lambda)
    r.map(_ * bc.value).collect.foreach(println)

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

Note: You shouldn't pass in the `Config Object` into `sc.broadcast()` directly, it would serialise your Config before transfer it to executors, however, your Config is not serialisable. Another thing to mention here: `Broadcast variable` do not fit well for your situation here, because you are only sharing a single value.

Comment: thank you so much!!!  what if my config class has too many variables?  in the first solution, should I declare  the Config as a Class and new a Config instance ?   how to pass it to executors?

Comment: is this correct ? def mul(rdd: RDD[Int]) = {
    val l = new Config()   l.lambda=0.02   
    rdd.map(_ * l.lambda)
  }

Comment: @user2848932, you should make your Config extends `Serializable` first if you want to do that

Comment: after extends Serializable, my code will work, right?

Comment: Thanks @YijieShen. Could you elaborate more on [2]? Is lazy val initialized just once for the Spark app or once per executor or once per partition? Could you throw some more light on this?