# Best way to initialize static variables in spark sql udf

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

what is the standard way to initialize static variables in spark sql udf in java.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685330/how-to-set-and-get-static-variables-from-spark